# Trying to add two numbers but they are wrapped in span tags

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add two numbers together, but they are dynamically generated in my page and are wrapped in  tags.  Can anyone tell me how I could add these numbers?

This would be an example of two dynamically generated numbers:

The id tags are ALSO dynamically generated.

```
<span id="thmr_35" class="thmr_call"> 42</span>
<span id="thmr_42" class="thmr_call"> 11</span>
```

I need to add the two numbers 42 + 11 and then spit out:
Total = 53

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are the id's always the same, and/or is the class only used for these to be added numbers?

Comment: What is your exact problem? How to get a reference the elements? How to get their text content? How to convert text to numbers? How do perform an addition in JavaScript?

Comment: What is your javascript code ?

Comment: I guess I need to somehow cut those strings so that I can just access the numbers inside them, and then add them.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the `span` elements with `getElementById`, and use the `innerHTML` property to get the contents of those. You can then use `parseInt` to convert those strings to numbers and add them together:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("thmr_35").innerHTML,
    num2 = document.getElementById("thmr_42").innerHTML,
    added = parseInt(num1, 10) + parseInt(num2, 10);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/K3A9K/6/) of the above.

Comment: Hey James, That was fast, thank you!  I forgot to mention that the id value is also dynamically generated.  So, I can never be sure what that id number will be.

Comment: @Adam Please show us your code as a sample. Maybe you can access their parent element and iterate over the children in a loop or select them in another way.

Comment: How are you generating these elements then? Server side? Client side based on an AJAX response?

Comment: The code is generated server side via PHP pulled from a database.

Comment: you can use getElementsByTagName('span') and access each span tag by it's index.

Comment: Could you use PHP to provide the argument? Something like: `document.getElementById("<?php echo "whatever"; ?>").innerHTML`. Or you need some other common identifier of the elements you want to access.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't use PHP because it's all preformatted from a Drupal module.  I agree, that I need a common identifier.  I was thinking of somehow cutting the string at the first ">" and then storing the values in there before the next "<"  I just don't know if there is an easier way or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If the id is dynamically generated like you say, you could access the elements through the class name.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('thmr_call');
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0;i < elems.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(elems[i].innerHTML, 10);
}
alert(sum);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K3A9K/7/

If also the class name is dynamically generated you can get the elements by the tag name.
`getElementsByTagName`
http://jsfiddle.net/K3A9K/8/