# How to Sum two Span values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two spans one called amtTotal and another called DeepGreenTotal.  I am trying to sum these two spans into the FinalTotal span you see below.  I would prefer to use javascript but if jquery is utilized please make the instructions super clear as i am new to jquery, for example where i would put the script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> because I have no idea.

```
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

        <span class="cena-vebsajt" id="amtTotal">$0.00</span>


       <span class="cena-hosting" id="DeepGreenTotal">$0.00</span>

      <span class="FinalTotal">$0.00</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to add two numbers but they are wrapped in span tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776850/trying-to-add-two-numbers-but-they-are-wrapped-in-span-tags)

Answer (score 2):

Just [get all the `<span>` elements by their identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), then [get their content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [replace the `$` symbol with an empty string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (we can only sum numeric values), [parse the two first string type values (the addends) to float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), and finally do the sum and show the result, [fixed to two decimal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), as part of the third `<span>` content.

```js
const 
    a = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#amtTotal").textContent.replace("$", "")),
    b = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#DeepGreenTotal").textContent.replace("$", "")),
    c = document.querySelector(".FinalTotal");

c.textContent = `$${(a + b).toFixed(2)}`;
```

```html
<span class="cena-vebsajt" id="amtTotal">$20.80</span> + 
<span class="cena-hosting" id="DeepGreenTotal">$71.50</span> = 
<span class="FinalTotal">$0.00</span>
```

I used [template strings (``)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for a more clear and clean visualization of the code's result.

Comment: Actually template literals do not form strings by concatenation they [interpolate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation)

Comment: @zer00ne You're right.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.numSpan').each(function() {
    // Add Mutation observer to watch for changes.
    new MutationObserver(function() {
      var val1 = parseFloat($('#amtTotal').text().replace(/[$,]+/g,""));
      var val2 = parseFloat($('#DeepGreenTotal').text().replace(/[$,]+/g,""));
      var total = val1 + val2;
      $('span.FinalTotal').text('$' + total);
    }).observe(this, {childList: true, subtree: true});
  });

  $("#btnAssignRandom").click(function(){
    // Generates and assigns a random number between 0 and 10 to the text of the span.
    $('span#amtTotal').text('$' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    $('span#DeepGreenTotal').text('$' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <span class="cena-vebsajt numSpan" id="amtTotal">$10.05</span>
       +
       <span class="cena-hosting numSpan" id="DeepGreenTotal">$5.08</span>
       =
       <span class="FinalTotal">$15.13</span>

<div>
  <button type="button" id="btnAssignRandom">Change Span Value</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

- You'll have to add the jQuery reference into the `<head>` tags.
- $(document).ready(function(){ [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp)

> The ready() method is used to make a function available after the
> document is loaded. Whatever code you write inside the $(document
> ).ready() method will run once the page DOM is ready to execute
> JavaScript code.

- $('.numSpan').each(function() {
  new MutationObserver(function() { [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

> Add Mutation observer to watch for changes.

- $("#btnAssignRandom").click(function(){ [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp)

> Bind an event handler to the "click" event, or trigger that event on
> an element.

- $('#amtTotal').text() [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp)

> Returns the text content of the selected elements.

- $('#amtTotal').text().replace(/[$,]+/g,"") [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

> Replaces commas ',' with an empty string to avoid errors using Regex.

- parseFloat() [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

> Parses a value as a string and returns the number as a float value.
> Then we can perform calculations.

- $('span.FinalTotal').text('$' + total); [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp)

> Writes the total into the span text.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the detail Indika!  I was wondering if it was possible to do without a button - to use an onchange or something to that nature so that when the amttotal span changes then the final total span changes with it?

Comment: Yeah, It's possible. 
I've updated the answer to listen for span text changes and calculate and update the final total.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
       <span class="cena-vebsajt" id="amtTotal">$10.05</span>
       +
       <span class="cena-hosting" id="DeepGreenTotal">$5.08</span>
       =
       <span class="FinalTotal">$0.00</span>

<div>
  <button type="button" id="btnCalculate">Calculate</button>
</div>
<script>
// Get element by ID
const getElById = (id) =>  document.getElementById(id);

// Get values from span
const getValuesFromSpan = (id) => parseFloat(getElById(id).textContent.replace('$', ''));

// Wait for the document to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Get the Calculate button element
  var btnCalculate = getElById('btnCalculate');
  
  // Attach click event handler to the Calculate button
  btnCalculate.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Get the values from the spans
    var amtTotal = getValuesFromSpan('amtTotal');
    var DeepGreenTotal = getValuesFromSpan('DeepGreenTotal');
    
    // Calculate the sum
    var sum = amtTotal + DeepGreenTotal;
    
    // Display the sum in the FinalTotal span
    document.querySelector('.FinalTotal').textContent = '$' + sum.toFixed(2);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the vanilla JavaScript code, we use the DOMContentLoaded event to ensure that JavaScript code executes after document is loaded.
One more thing by placing the JavaScript at the end of the HTML, it provides time to load HTML first and then load the javascript; this approach improves render speed.

We get the Calculate button element using getElementById and attach a click event listener to it using addEventListener.

When the button is clicked, we retrieve the values from the spans by getting the textContent and removing the dollar sign using the replace() method.

We parse the extracted values as floats using parseFloat().

Then, we calculate the sum of the two values and store it in the sum variable. Finally, we update the textContent of the. FinalTotal span with the calculated sum, formatted as a currency value using toFixed(2).

Comment: Hi Vishal thank you so much! Unfortunately it cannot be a button.  So I was wondering if there was javascript/jquery to grab the "Final Total" when the span changes - the amount total span changes, the final total span changes?